# Reaction of a cyclic tertiary alcohol with chromic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, organic-oxidation

We know that $\ce{H2CrO4}$ cannot oxidize tertiary alcohols. The mechanism is:

[image]

Now the ${\alpha}$ carbon does not have any hydrogen to proceed to next step. Therefore, this reaction would not occur.

Is there any possibility of dehydration due to acidic medium?

Comment: If you are talking about normal dehydration conditions, then yes.. however under mild conditions no reaction takes place.

Comment: @Apurvium Take a look at the phenomenon of **Carbonyl Transposition**. That will be the case here.

Comment: @Safdar I am unable to find any example for dehydration through chromic acid in any condition.

Comment: It is normally given as $\ce{H+} $and not $\ce{H2CrO4}$

Comment: See Reference 2 here on carbonyl transposition: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134863/why-cant-we-oxidise-allylic-alcohol-to-aldehyde-using-pyridinium-chlorochromate/134868#134868