# Sigmatropic Rearrangement along with oxidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, grignard-reagent, rearrangements

I was going through an organic chemistry book I came along this question it's solution used sigmatropic rearrangement along with oxidation in Jones reagent, how does this rearrangement work??
[image]

Comment: As to the oxidative rearrangement, look [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134863/why-cant-we-oxidise-allylic-alcohol-to-aldehyde-using-pyridinium-chlorochromate/134868#134868).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the mechanism of chromium trioxide oxidation (see below - from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_oxidation)) you will see that it proceeds *via* the formation of a chromate ester which is then displaced by water. Since there is no solvent water present in the reaction system this gives the opportunity for the loss of the chromium species to proceed by an intramolecular reaction whereby one of the oxygens on the chromium does a sigmatropic rearragement with allylic alcohol pushing the double bond to the tertiary centre expelling the cyclic intermediate chromate species and leaving the chromate ester at the methylene. The oxidation then proceeds at this centre giving the unsaturated ketone product shown.

[image]